# How does large address aware (LAA) work in Wine?

Tags: wine, ram

Can anybody clarify how support for large address aware (LAA) for 32-bit applications works in Wine?

I know that by default in Windows, 32-bit applications are limited to a maximum of 2GB of RAM; however, it is possible to set an LAA flag on the executable, to allow it to use up to 4GB.

My understanding is that, by default, Wine respects this 2GB limit for 32-bit Windows applications and it will allow 4GB to be used, if the LAA flag is set on the .exe. However, I have heard that there is also a global option that can be set for Wine to automatically allow 4GB for all 32-bit Windows applications - `LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE=1` (or something like that?).

Can someone please clarify if that is the correct environment variable? Does it work in vanilla Wine, or just in Wine-staging? Is it also required when running 32-bit applications in a 64-bit Wine prefix? I thought there was a Wine user guide page about it, but I have been unable to find it.

Comment: It didn't work for me: https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48172

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov that is interesting, but it seems like a different issue? I am not asking about allocating a large continuous block of memory - I am asking about the 2/4 GB limit for 32-bit executables. I know that Wine has built-in support for large address aware - if you enable the LAA flag on a 32-bit executable, then Wine will see that and give the application 4 GB. I have done that in the past for some games. I am asking for more details about how LAA is implemented in Wine, and whether there is an environment variable to enable it globally.

Comment: Wine fails to allocate a 1.5GB block of data in 32bit mode, so to me it sounds like LAA is simply not supported in any shape or form. I could be wrong though but I've not heard anything to the contrary.

Comment: I've found a third-party yet to be merged patch to enable LAA in Wine: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=32854 Also I've found out that Proton has LAA support but Proton is Wine with a ton of patches. Sounds like vanilla Wine doesn't support LAA.

Comment: Also this https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/search?q=LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE&type=code -> winegcc has a flag for it, and winedump shows if this option is enabled. There's seemingly no code to support LAA.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have most definitely used LAA in Wine for 32-bit applications in the past, so I know the feature is supported, at least to some extent. I used it to run Dawn of War 1 with the Unification mod (which is 32-bit but requires >2 GB of RAM in Windows, otherwise it is known to crash). I think that was in Wine-Staging though, and I am confused in general about the level of support for LAA in Wine/Wine-Staging.

Comment: Of course, it's possible things may have regressed in that area ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a patch that you can install for each x86 application you are trying to run under WINE which you can find here: https://ntcore.com/?page_id=371

Additionally, there is a patch for WINE for setting the LAA flag in PE files. Taking a look at the contents of the files included in the github, it appears you are correct that the variable you are looking for is `LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` https://github.com/randomstuff/pe-set-laa. According to the creator of this patch, it will work under WINE proper.

Depending on what you are trying to run (Games or Portable Executables) it seems there is some inconsistency regarding the efficacy of the flag with certain applications.

If you want to build Wine from source, you can also use this code to patch LAA on globally.

```
diff --git a/dlls/kernel32/heap.c b/dlls/kernel32/heap.c
index cac73ec..fb214b9 100644
--- a/dlls/kernel32/heap.c
+++ b/dlls/kernel32/heap.c
@@ -1423,6 +1423,7 @@ VOID WINAPI GlobalMemoryStatus( LPMEMORYSTATUS lpBuffer )
 
     /* values are limited to 2Gb unless the app has the IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag */
     /* page file sizes are not limited (Adobe Illustrator 8 depends on this) */
+/*
     if (!(nt->FileHeader.Characteristics & IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE))
     {
         if (lpBuffer->dwTotalPhys > MAXLONG) lpBuffer->dwTotalPhys = MAXLONG;
@@ -1430,7 +1431,7 @@ VOID WINAPI GlobalMemoryStatus( LPMEMORYSTATUS lpBuffer )
         if (lpBuffer->dwTotalVirtual > MAXLONG) lpBuffer->dwTotalVirtual = MAXLONG;
         if (lpBuffer->dwAvailVirtual > MAXLONG) lpBuffer->dwAvailVirtual = MAXLONG;
     }
-
+*/
     /* work around for broken photoshop 4 installer */
     if ( lpBuffer->dwAvailPhys +  lpBuffer->dwAvailPageFile >= 2U*1024*1024*1024)
          lpBuffer->dwAvailPageFile = 2U*1024*1024*1024 -  lpBuffer->dwAvailPhys - 1;
diff --git a/dlls/ntdll/virtual.c b/dlls/ntdll/virtual.c
index 4d4bc3b..2c2264c 100644
--- a/dlls/ntdll/virtual.c
+++ b/dlls/ntdll/virtual.c
@@ -1845,7 +1845,7 @@ void virtual_set_large_address_space(void)
 {
     IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *nt = RtlImageNtHeader( NtCurrentTeb()->Peb->ImageBaseAddress );
 
-    if (!(nt->FileHeader.Characteristics & IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE)) return;
+    // if (!(nt->FileHeader.Characteristics & IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE)) return;
     /* no large address space on win9x */
     if (NtCurrentTeb()->Peb->OSPlatformId != VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) return;
```

Comment: This is helpful information - thanks! So, it seems that patch modifies the PE header to enable large address aware. Are you aware of any patch for Wine that can enable LAA globally, for a given prefix?

Comment: How useful this patch can be if Wine seemingly doesn't support the feature?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov where you say the feature isn't supported: you mean that Wine will always impose the 2 GB memory limit for 32-bit applications, regardless of flags or modifications to executables? If so, that would be very good to know; however, I am skeptical, as I have the impression that Wine has some level of support for LAA.

Comment: While wine does not support LAA directly, applications can be patched individually while running under wine to allow for up to 4GB. Because of this you would have to patch each application, which can get tedious. Neither WINE or winetricks mention LAA in any documentation I can find, so it is likely the documentation you referred to regarding global env for LAA was in regards to a patch for proton via steam.

Comment: You could always use proton for steam, in which you can set steam launch option PROTON_FORCE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE=1 %command% to force LAA On all titles for proton. It may be simpler for you to run whatever applications you want through that, rather than individually install the applications via wine prefixes and then patch them with either of the tools mentioned above.

Comment: Regarding the usefulness of the patch. Surely it is useful if it adds a feature to an application that said application currently lacks.

Comment: Thanks for the additions to your answer. So, it seems the bottom line is that vanilla Wine will recognize the LAA flag if it is set on the executable, and give the application 4 GB. However, only Proton has an option to enable LAA globally, unless you patch Wine before building. I appreciate your efforts to explain and I will award you the bounty - thanks!